# listen to intent in background

Tags: android, android-intent, service

I am new to android, I have created intent's like this -

```
<receiver android:name=".IncommigCallListener" >
      <intent-filter>
             <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
      </intent-filter>
</receiver>
<receiver android:name=".OutgoingCallReciever" >
         <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
         </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Now i created a service like this -

```
<service
       android:name=".CallLogger"
       android:exported="false"/>
```

Class `CallLogger`

```
public class CallLogger extends IntentService {
    public CallLogger(String name) {
        super(name);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("service started");
    }
}
```

I don't want to have any activity in my application, i just want to start the service so that it can work in background and receive `PHONE_STATE` and `NEW_OUTGOING_CALL` intent.

When i start this application, it doesn't log anything on `PHONE_STATE` or `NEW_OUTGOING_CALL` intent.

How can start service in background without using any activity ?

**Edit :**

```
public class OutgoingCallReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context ctx, Intent intent) {
         String number = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
    }
}
```

and

```
public class IncommigCallListener extends PhoneStateListener {
    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
        switch (state) {
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
            String incommingCallNumber = incomingNumber;
            System.out.println("incomming call : " + incomingNumber);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just start service in your BroadcastReceiver's onReceive method. As you are registering BroadcastReceiver in AndroidManifist, It will always listen for Broadcasts even if application is not running (OS will run it for you). 
**Example**

```
 public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

  @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
     Intent service = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
     context.startService(service);
    }
   }
```

**EDIT**
To start a service on Boot completed you can do something like this.

1) Add permission to your Manifist :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

2) Register your Broadcast Receiver with BOOT COMPLETE action.

```
<receiver android:name="com.example.BootBroadcastReceiver">  
    <intent-filter>  
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />  
    </intent-filter>  
</receiver>
```

3) In BootBroadcastReceiver.java:

```
public class BootBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
        context.startService(serviceIntent );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do something like this in your receiver.

```
public class OutgoingCallReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context ctx, Intent intent) {
         String number = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
         Intent service = new Intent(context, CallLogger.class);
         context.startService(service);
    }
}
```

You need to create an intent and call startService() on it to "launch" the service.

Also for what it's worth you should get out of the habbit of `System.out.println` use `Log.d(tag,msg)` to print debugging information to the logcat. You can switch the `d` to other letters if you want to print in different channels.

Answer (score 0):

Why nothing gets printed is only due to the problem that `System.out.println` does not work in Android! Where do you think the background process will "`print`" this thing?

You need to change that to `Log.d(tag, msg)` and then check your logcat to see the output! Otherwise I guess your code might be running properly.